# MYSQL Column Collations: Difference between latin1 and latin2

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation, iso-8859-1, iso-8859-2

I was currently setting up a database for a webpage when I ran over the Column Collations `latin1` and `latin2` in PhpMyAdmin. After research on the difference, the only thing I found was that latin1 is for west-europeans and latin2 for central-europeans. What´s the difference in the charset, though?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1    ...  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2

Comment: @scaisEdge thanks ;)

Comment: You should just use utf8. I would even prefer utf8mb4, but PHP clients don't support it yet.

Comment: @BillKarwin could you please clarify what do you mean by PHP clients here... ?

Comment: @AmarjeetChaudhary: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74461

Comment: @BillKarwin This is a pretty old question of mine; I´m using utf8mb4 as encoding by now. I´m not getting any problems with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Charset is what is different.  The Collation is the ordering of the characters; since there are different characters in the two charsets, it is not relevant to talk about differences in collation.

First pick `latin1` or `latin2` based on what characters you need.  (Better yet, pick `utf8` so you can get both sets of characters.)  Second, pick the collation desired.  (Often, the default collation is "good enough".)

Comment: Thanks! That clarified it for me :)